# TableView Search Bar Freezes

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

Using the standard search bar for my tableview set up. There can be up to 1000 values to search through (which shouldn't be too costly).

**Problem: The search bar lags for 30-90 seconds if I enter a single character in. CPU and Memory are at 100%.** Have I implemented the searchbardel incorrectly?

#### TableView Cell

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("RestaurantCell") as UITableViewCell
    var name : Name
    // Check to see whether search results table is being displayed
    if tableView == self.searchDisplayController!.searchResultsTableView {
        name = self.filteredNames[indexPath.row]
    } else {
        name = self.names[indexPath.row]
    }

    cell.textLabel?.text = name.name
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.DisclosureIndicator
    return cell
}
```

#### Filter Code

```
func filterContentForSearchText(searchText: String, scope: String = "All") {
    self.filteredNames = self.names.filter({( name : Name) -> Bool in
        var categoryMatch = (scope == "All") || (name.city == scope)
        var stringMatch = name.name.rangeOfString(searchText)
        self.filterRestaurants(searchText)
        return categoryMatch && (stringMatch != nil)
    })
}

func filterRestaurants(filteredObject: String) {
    selectFilteredRestaurantArray = self.selectRestaurantArray.filter()  {
        if let type = ($0 as PFObject)["Name"] as? String {
            return type.rangeOfString(filteredObject) != nil
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
}

func searchDisplayController(controller: UISearchDisplayController!, shouldReloadTableForSearchString searchString: String!) -> Bool {
    self.filterContentForSearchText(searchString)
    return true
}

func searchDisplayController(controller: UISearchDisplayController!, shouldReloadTableForSearchScope searchOption: Int) -> Bool {
    self.filterContentForSearchText(self.searchDisplayController!.searchBar.text)
    return true
}
```

Comment: have u tested this on real device?if you test on  simulator of xcode6 or 6.1. sumulator of xcode6.1 behave this way many time.If you not test this on real device test it, may be this problem not found on real device.

Comment: tried on two actual devices and both have the issue (iphone 5 and iphone 6 plus)

Comment: try running your search in the background and pop to the main thread when it completes. the issue is clearly that your search is taking too long